# Thread Safety - declaring a new thread inside method local block

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I am curious if the following code is thread-safe:

```
public static void methodA () {
    // given that mutableObject is not thread-safe (no lock/synchronization used)
    MutableObject mo = new MutableObject();
    mo.setSomeValue(100);  // set an int value

    // the mutableList variable must be final in order to pass it to the thread block
    final List<mutableObject> mutableList = new ArrayList<mutableObject>();  
    mutableList.add(mo);
    Thread t = new Thread() {
                      @Override 
                      public void run() {
                          for (mutableObject e : mutableList) {
                              e.printIntValue();  // print 100 or 0?
                          }
                      }
                }
    t.start();
}
```

so, here is the question.
I am not sure whether all contents reachable* from the "mutableList" reference are visible to the new thread even though there is no explicit synchronization/locking used. (visibility issue) In other words, would the new thread print 0 or 100? it would print 0 if it does not see the value 100 set by the main thread as 0 is the default primitive value of the int data type.

ie. "contents reachable" means:

1. the int value 100 which is held by the MutableObject
2. the reference to the MutableObject held by the ArrayList

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Anything that happens before `t.start()` will be visible in the `run` method of the new thread.

Comment: does it mean that we do not need to "safely publish" an object from thread A to thread B actually if we can make sure that thread B starts after thread A setting the object to a public reference (i.e. public static variable) ?

Comment: Starting a thread creates a happens before relationship so the object IS safely published to Thread B. If however Thread A modifies the object AFTER having started Thread B, no visibility guarantee is provided.

Comment: A now deleted answer to your question nicely adressed that point. Maybe the author will undelete it.

Comment: In JCIP section16.2.3, the author said "Static initializers are run by the JVM at class initialization time, after class loading but before the class is used by any thread. Because the JVM acquires a lock during initialization and this lock is acquired by each thread at least once to ensure that the class has been loaded, memory writes made during static initialization are automatically visible to all threads.".....So, actually the lock mentioned here is NOT necessary for visibility as all threads start after static initialization. Am I correct?  (thanks for answering)

Comment: just in case there is misunderstanding, I am not saying that the lock mentioned could be eliminated as the lock could have other uses. What I would like to say is that the lock is unnecessary for visibility purpose.

Comment: You are confusing things here. This quote only applies to static initialisers visibility and has nothing to do with your initial question. By the way, it happens all the time that a thread starts before a class' static initializer is run.

Comment: So yes that lock IS necessary for visibility purposes.

Comment: oic, thank you, very helpful. So, does it mean when we invoke t.start() to start a new thread, all states and variable values in the JVM visible/reachable by the new thread are guaranteed to be up-to-date? (although state changes after starting are not guaranteed to be visible)

Comment: yes that's the idea. See [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-320) for a list of operations that create a happens-before relationship. One of them is: "*A call to `start()` on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.*" - by transitivity, all actions that are executed before the call to `start()` will also *happen-before* any actions in the started thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is thread-safe because there is not way that any other thread will access *the same* objects because they are available inside `methodA()` and in method `run()` of your thread. Both do not change the data.

Thread safety problems appear when at least 2 threads operate the same data. This is not your case.

How to make you code thread-unsafe? 
There are several ways.

1. add line `mo.setSomeValue(100);` after calling `t.start()`. This means that after staring the thread there are 2 threads (your main thread and your other thread) that operate the same object `mo`. This will no however cause exceptions.
2. add line `mutableList.remove(0)`. This *may* cause `ConcurrentModificationException` if your thread starts quickly enough and manages to enter the loop before main thread arrives to remove instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.
My question focuses on "data race" actually, which is..."You risk a data race whenever a thread writes a variable that might next be read by another thread or reads a variable that might have last been written by another thread if both threads do no use synchronization;" accordiing to JCIP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question of thread safety here.
The objects `mo` and `mutableList` are both defined and instantiated within the function call.  Each time the function is called 2 new objects (above) are being created.  No thread-unsafe values whatsoever.